# JQuery# Live Filter conflict with Fancy Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, fancybox

Live filter, source: `[jsfiddle/M2mUF/][1]` is in conflict with fancy Box`s libraries(jquery live filter library in conflict with fancy libraries [fancyapps/fancybox/](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/). I need a popup iframe script which no conflict with live filter library. 
Other multi filter testing is [tommyp.github.io/multifilter/](http://tommyp.github.io/multifilter/) , but this is in conflict with fancy box or other popup script.
Please, help me!

Comment: please explain brief. i can't understand

Comment: fancy box in conflict with live filter, jquery library from fancy is in conflict with library from live filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use jquery's method -  `jQuery.noConflict()`, it is specifically designed for preventing jquery from conflicting with any other scripts . Here is its [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for further refrence
 on how to use it..

Comment: I repair my old code for popup and now not exist conflict with live filter, thaks Pramod, your solution helped me, 50%!